# Magento 2 Get all Orders sort by latest orders

Tags: magento2.3, orders, rest-api

I am using the below Rest api to fetch all orders in desc i.e the latest on top but its not working

```
index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria=all&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=order_id&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

By default result will be ASC order i.e oldest order first

If you need the latest order, You need to set DESC order in search Criteria

You can try below code:

```
index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria=all&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=entity_id&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=DESC
```

Hope above will help!

Answer (score 0):

To get all orders sorted by the latest orders in Magento 2, you can use the following code:

```
    use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
    use Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrderBuilder;
    use Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrder;
     
    class YourClass
    {
        protected $orderFactory;
        protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        protected $sortOrderBuilder;
     
        public function __construct(
            OrderFactory $orderFactory,
            SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
            SortOrderBuilder $sortOrderBuilder
        ) {
            $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
            $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
            $this->sortOrderBuilder = $sortOrderBuilder;
        }
     
        public function getOrders()
        {
            $sortOrder = $this->sortOrderBuilder
                ->setField('created_at')
                ->setDescendingDirection()
                ->create();
     
            $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
                ->addSortOrder($sortOrder)
                ->create();
     
            $orders = $this->orderFactory->create()->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
     
            return $orders;
        }
    }
```

Here, we are using the OrderFactory class to create an instance of the order model. We are also using the SearchCriteriaBuilder and SortOrderBuilder classes to build the search criteria and sort order for the orders.

In the getOrders() method, we are setting the sort order to sort by the created_at field in descending order (latest orders first). We then create the search criteria with the sort order and use the order model to retrieve the list of orders that match the search criteria. Finally, we return the list of orders.

You can call the getOrders() method in your code to get the list of orders sorted by the latest orders.